# Logging simple text in Apache Camel logs

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is is possible to log simple text in Camel as follows

```
    <route>
     <from uri="direct:cxlrefdata"/>
     <to uri="log:'Hello World'" />
   </route>
```

I want to log this message, 'Hello World' in log, but all the examples which I find in Apache Camel site are for logging route messages.

e.g

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:t1"/>
  <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
</route>
```

I want something simple which can log test messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes see the log eip
http://camel.apache.org/logeip.html

This allows you to log human readable messages to the log. You could have spotted it, by the green tip box on the log component page: http://camel.apache.org/log

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR**
>
> - DO NOT forget about `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` in `application.properties`
> - from("timer://scheduler?fixedRate=true&period=5s")
>                 .log("Hello World!");

Let me provide you the simplest example written in Java DSL. I will use the Spring Boot Camel starter to setup the simplest runnable piece of code. This example will help you to log the message `Hello World!` to your console every 5 seconds according to `quartz2` component `cron` expression.

> Documentation to look through:
>
> - Spring Boot & Apache Camel - https://camel.apache.org/spring-boot
> - Camel's Quartz2 component - http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html

Here is your simplest Spring Boot demo application:

```
 package com.lordnighton.camel.demo;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

 @SpringBootApplication
 public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

 }
```

Here is the simplest route that logs the message `HelloWorld!` into console every 5 seconds:

```
 package com.lordnighton.camel.demo.routes;

 import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 @Component
 public class LogMessageRoute extends RouteBuilder {

     @Override
     public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("quartz2://logMessageGroup/logMessageTimer?cron=0/5+*+*+*+*+?")
           .log("Hello World!");
     }

}
```